# How to secure Spring Data REST associations requests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'v created REST API using Spring Data REST. I have entity `User` and `Post`, where `User` can have multiple posts (One to Many). Now I need to add posts to my user. But I need that `userA` can't have possibilities to delete or update posts of `userB`.

**Api structure**

```
{
    "_links": {
        "users": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/users{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "posts": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/posts{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        }
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/profile"
        }
    }
}
```

**User structure**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": null,
    "password": null,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/users/1"
        },
        "user": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/users/1"
        },
        "posts": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/users/1/posts"
        }
    }
}
```

There are several ways to add related entity throw links.
Using `PUT` method and `text/uri-list` content type:

```
PUT /api/posts/1/user? HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Content-Type: text/uri-list
Authorization: Bearer 270c6dc3-04a5-48cc-b42e-c275472df459
cache-control: no-cache
http://localhost:8081/api/users/1
```

But with this way I can add any URI to body and add any random user to random post, and I think, there is a security problem here.
Next method to add related resource is to add it in JSON like this:

```
PATCH /api/posts/1? HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer 270c6dc3-04a5-48cc-b42e-c275472df459
cache-control: no-cache
{
    "user": "http://localhost:8081/api/users/1"
}
```

But and in this method the same problem. Any user can be added to any post.

Now I see only one solve of this problem - is customizing rest repository and check if added user is current authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your use case "Only User is responsible for CRUD operation on its POST"

Yes one way of solving this would be "is customizing rest repository and check if added user is current authenticated user."

Assuming you have Spring Security

I would suggest you don't pass any User id for your Posts and pick up User from Logged in User ID from Security Context or from Token.

This way your post will be independent of User at API level.